# Pourquoi est-ce que ces verbes sont suivis de « de » et pas par « par » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes

Le jeu de mot dans le titre est intentionnel. À la page 13 de *Advanced French Grammar* de V. Mazet :

> The direct object of the main verb becomes the apparent subject of the verb in a passive sentence. The true subject, aka the agent, is usually introduced by **par**. A few verbs require **de** instead: for example, redouter *(dread)*, craindre *(fear)*, obéir *(obey)*, suivre *(follow)*.

Pourquoi ? Je veux éviter de mémoriser et d'approuver ces règles, car je les oublierai d'ici peu et bien trop tôt.

Comment: Si tu veux éviter de t'encombrer la mémoire de règles inutiles oublie vite celle-ci, on peut dire " être redouté par", " être suivi par", "être obéi par", "être craint par" (même si dans ce dernier cas *de* semble plus fréquent). Au vu des nombreuses citations que tu fais de cette grammaire, je de grands doutes sur sa fiabilité.

Answer (score 1):

La liste de Mazet laisse très à désirer.

- *Obéir* est un cas étrange, car le sujet du verbe au passif est un *objet indirect* du verbe actif.
- *Redouté par* est une construction parfaitement valide, *de* étant une formule plus recherchée.
- *Suivi de* **n'est pas la formule passive normale** pour le sens de base de *suivre*. Elle s'emploie quand le verbe a le sens de "avoir lieu juste après". Dans le sens normal, "avancer à la suite de, traquer", *par* est la seule formulation possible.

*Craindre* est le seul verbe de la liste où *de* demeure la construction la plus commune de l'agent au passif.

Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 14e ed., §319) classe les constructions avec *de* en trois catégories:

1. Quand on indique un résultat, avec une formulation se rapprochant d'un adjectif suivie d'un complément adjectival: *La place était ornée de drapeau/recouverte de débris/encombrée de stalles*. On dira au contraire *La places fut recouverte **par** l'eau lors de l'inondation*, car il s'agit d'une "action".
2. Les verbes au figuré, qui présentent alors un double usage plus marqué sémantiquement, comme *suivre* mentionné plus tôt.
3. Les verbes exprimant un sentiment: *aimer*, *admirer*, *craindre*.

De nombreux verbes des catégories 2 et 3 semblent de nos jours admettre *par* à des degrés divers dans la langue usuelle. C'est surtout notable avec des verbes comme *accabler* où la distinction sémantique est moins marquée: on dira indifféremment *accablé par les soucis* et *accablé de soucis* (mais l'inverse n'est pas vrai: *accablé de chaleur* ne se dit pas). Dans le cas de *craindre*, son usage au passif appartenant à un niveau de langue plus recherché influence probablement la domination de *de* (même si on rencontre *par*).

Signalons encore le cas de *connaître*, qui entre dans la première catégorie, mais particulier car la préposition est très fréquemment omise lorsque l'agent est un pronom:

> *La situation est connue du gouvernement.*
>
> *La situation nous est connue.* (par comparaison: *La situation nous est familière.*, où la préposition est *à*.)

Answer (score 0):

Je voudrais verser à la réponse de Circeus un exemple :

● Obéir est un cas étrange, car le sujet du verbe au passif est un objet indirect du verbe actif.

Exemple: La bienséance a été obéi de soi. On obéit à la bienséance.

Answer (score -1):

[Disclaimer: I am French, but I am not a French teacher]

Based on my intuition, the subject is introduced by "par" when it is a person, and is introduced by "de" when it is an action.

Comment: Mais comment une action peut-elle craindre, redouter ou obéir ?