# Translation of « by » : « par » ou « de »

Tags: prépositions

I've received an email that says "Votre dossier est toujours à l'étude de la faculté"

Shouldn't "de la faculté" be "par la faculté" ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but I'm linking those related questions so people who stumble upon this one can find more information on the de/par alternation: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29552/traduction-de-by-par-ou-de https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/pourquoi-est-ce-que-ces-verbes-sont-suivis-de-de-et-pas-par-par https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/Être-adoré-par-et-être-adoré-de https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/how-to-understand-suivre-des-yeux-syntactically

Answer (score 3):

It could mean your documents are still in the office of the university.  Etude tends to be a legal office, but I don't think it's entirely impossible a university would use that word. Especially if there was a legal dimension to your documents?

Answer (score 1):

You are right questioning the sentence. The set expression ***être** (toujours) **à l'étude*** means "**to be** (still) **under scrutiny**" so I would expect too ***par*** or ***à*** here:

> *Votre dossier **est** toujours **à l'étude** `par` (les services de) la faculté*, i.e. is still being evaluated by the faculty competent department.
>
> *Votre dossier **est** toujours **à l'étude** `à` la faculté*, i.e. is still being evaluated in the faculty.

On the other hand, the sentence you got can be understood as:

> *Votre dossier est toujours à **l'étude de la faculté**.*

might mean the unlikely :

> Your documents are still located in "the study hall of the faculty".

Where ***étude*** describes a location:

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tude)

> III.− Lieu où s'exerce une activité studieuse, un effort de l'esprit.
> A.− Salle de travail où les élèves font leurs devoirs ou apprennent leurs leçons en dehors des heures de classe.

I'm ruling out too the possibility for *étude* to mean:

> B.− Locaux où travaille un officier public ou ministériel, avec ses clercs. C'est dans l'étude d'un avoué qu'il faut apprendre la véritable langue de notre barreau (Jouy, Hermite,t. 1, 1811, p. 97)

because this acception nowadays essentially applies to *notaires* and *huissiers de justice*, none of whom are expected to have an office in a university.

Comment: Une autre question de l'OP me fait croire que le dossier dont il s'agit est une demande de bourse. Stricto sensu, la *faculté*, ce n'est **que** le corps professoral. Et ce n'est pas lui qui s'occupe du traitement des dossiers de bourse. Donc je crois qu'il faut exclure **par**.

Comment: @aCOSwt La faculté est plus, il me semble, le lieu où l'enseignement est prodigué (*on s'est rencontré à la fac(ulté)*) que le seul corps professoral. Je ne vois pas d'autre question de l'OP.

Comment: My bad! J'avais confondu avec https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39671/what-does-jusqu%C3%A0-trois-trimestres-%C3%A0-la-fois-mean . Après, oui! Tu as raison! Le mot *faculté* s'est étendu. Mais peut-être est-il encore quelques âmes internes pour faire la distinction... :-)

Answer (score 1):

La phrase mentionnée est trop ambigüe pour qu'on puisse la comprendre avec certitude.

La phrase pourrait potentiellement s'interpréter comme « votre dossier est toujours *soumis à* l'étude de la faculté » pour indiquer que l'étape d'un processus n'est pas terminée.